# Check Status of URLs in content of given URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo

First of all, I am working in JavaScript and can use npm plugins.
My requirement is as follows (it's kind of SEO)
- Given URL e.g. www.xyz.com
- First check HTTP status of given URL
- Then if it's ok, have to check status of all URL in its content (probably simply HTML document). Which includes all `<a>` tag urls, all .js and .css urls, i.e. All URL in that content

I tried calling Ajax and I get HTML content as response. Then I parse it and find URLs like

`$("[href] [src] [action]", $(response));`

then I iterate over it and check status using Ajax.

But I still think there can be more better way to check. Because here still I can't get status of all URLs.

As there are some web sites available to check, for example, https://monitorbacklinks.com/seo-tools/http-header-status-check

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't do this in browser due to `same origin policy`. As for asking about services , questions like those are off topic here. Would be simple enough to check yourself from your server

Comment: This won't work in a browser if sites don't allow cross-origin access.

Comment: I know that policy. I think one workaround is to use proxy. But I'm doing this tool as chrome extension and there it's not giving any exception of same origin policy. Anyway, can we do from server side? Like PHP. That's also fine if we can.

Comment: Try making a HEAD request in the extension. Otherwise use cURL in php on server to make HEAD request